# Spark SQL DataFrame HAVING

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using pyspark, I have a Spark 2.2 DataFrame `df` with schema: `country: String, year: Integer, x: Float`
I want the average value of `x` over years for each country, for countries with `AVG(x) > 10`.
The following is working:

```
groups = df.groupBy(df.country).agg(avg('x').alias('avg_x'))
groups.filter(groups.avg_x > 10)
```

But I am bothered to have to define the useless `groups` variable.

I have tried:

```
df.groupBy(df.country).agg(avg('x').alias('avg_x')).filter(df.avg_x > 10)
```

But this results in: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'avg_x'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use column bounded to a `DataFrame` (which just doesn't have `avg_x`):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.groupBy(df.country).agg(avg('x').alias('avg_x')).filter(col("avg_x") > 10)
```

or

```
df.groupBy(df.country).agg(avg('x').alias('avg_x')).filter("avg_x > 10")
```

Comment: perfect ! I didn't know one could use an SQL string condition in `filter()`. I wonder why there is no `filterExpr()`, in the same way there is `selectExpr()` for SQL expressions